# Error in db.eval() in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, mongo-java

I am trying to run a *map-reduce* script using `db.eval()` method.

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB mongodb = (DB) mongo.getDB("testDB");

    String script = "db.collection.mapReduce("
            + "function() {emit(this.class, this.marks);},"
            + "function(key, values) { return {\"sum\":Array.sum(values)};},"
               + "{ "
                   + " query : {_id:{$lt:50}},"
                   + "out:\"collectionMapReduce\""
               + "}"
           + ")";

    Object result = mongodb.eval(script);
```

I got the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server localhost:27017 failed on database testDB
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:298)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:269)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:320)
at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:299)
at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:374)
at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:246)
at com.mongodb.DB.doEval(DB.java:445)
at com.mongodb.DB.eval(DB.java:463)
at com.dev.TestMapReduce.main(TestMapReduce.java:25)

Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:75)
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:50)
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:37)
at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:42)
at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:164)
at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:158)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:187)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:158)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:290)
... 9 more
```

I am not able to understand the reason for this error. How can I resolve this?

> Note: I am able to perform this job using `db.collection.mapReduce()`.
>   But I am just trying to achieve this using `db.eval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to run a map/reduce job is via the [`mapReduce` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) which is exposed in the Java driver via the [`MapReduceCommand` helper](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/).

The [`eval` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) is not intended for this purpose (and has also been deprecated as at MongoDB 3.0).